# Touchpad stopped working - can't see any events

Tags: touchpad, elantech, events

I have Ubuntu 22.04 running on an Acer Swift SF314-42

The touchpad has always worked perfectly but not today. Some days ago I got few small drops of light rain on the keyboard, I dried it immediately with some kitchen paper and there was very little of it anyway so I'm optimistic that this is unrelated.

I tried re-booting, I tried both Wayland and Xorg, sadly I see no life from the touchpad either way.

In addition to the Touchpad I also have a Logitech M525 mouse which continues to work OK.

I've done some DuckDucking re how to diagnose the problem. Below is an extract from:

~$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=312b Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN0504:01
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN0504:01/0018:04F3:312B.0001/input/input28
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event10 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

When running Xorg, xinput list gives me the following

```
~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K400                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M525                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer Wireless Radio Control               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD User Facing: HD User Facing            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech K400                             id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

When running Wayland, I get the following

```
$ xinput list
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:17                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:17              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:17                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The page:
https://devicetests.com/fix-touchpad-not-working-ubuntu
led me to try:

```
~$ sudo dmesg | fgrep -i elan
[    1.041238] input: ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN0504:01/0018:04F3:312B.0001/input/input5
[    1.041370] input: ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN0504:01/0018:04F3:312B.0001/input/input7
[    1.041456] hid-generic 0018:04F3:312B.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B] on i2c-ELAN0504:01
[    4.592854] input: ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN0504:01/0018:04F3:312B.0001/input/input26
[    4.592999] input: ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN0504:01/0018:04F3:312B.0001/input/input28
[    4.593096] hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:312B.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B] on i2c-ELAN0504:01
~$ sudo dmesg | fgrep -i touch
[    1.041370] input: ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN0504:01/0018:04F3:312B.0001/input/input7
[    4.592999] input: ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN0504:01/0018:04F3:312B.0001/input/input28
[    4.593096] hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:312B.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B] on i2c-ELAN0504:01
```

The page: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400153/how-to-find-logs-about-touchpad-malfunction-in-debian-on-wayland
persuaded me to try "evtest", this I had to install using:

```
sudo apt install evtest
```

Evtest displays a list of input devices,
asks you to select one and then displays supported events
followed by actual events from that device.
For me the Touchpad is 10

```
~$ sudo evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Power Button
/dev/input/event1:  Sleep Button
/dev/input/event2:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event3:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event5:  Acer WMI hotkeys
/dev/input/event6:  ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Mouse
/dev/input/event7:  Logitech M525
/dev/input/event8:  Logitech K400
/dev/input/event9:  Acer Wireless Radio Control
/dev/input/event10: ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Touchpad
/dev/input/event11: HD User Facing: HD User Facing
/dev/input/event12: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event13: HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone
Select the device event number [0-13]: 10
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x18 vendor 0x4f3 product 0x312b version 0x100
Input device name: "ELAN0504:01 04F3:312B Touchpad"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER)
    Event code 328 (BTN_TOOL_QUINTTAP)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP)
    Event code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP)
    Event code 335 (BTN_TOOL_QUADTAP)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     3204
      Resolution      32
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     1945
      Resolution      32
    Event code 47 (ABS_MT_SLOT)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        4
    Event code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     3204
      Resolution      32
    Event code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     1945
      Resolution      32
    Event code 55 (ABS_MT_TOOL_TYPE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        2
    Event code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    65535
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP)
Properties:
  Property type 0 (INPUT_PROP_POINTER)
  Property type 2 (INPUT_PROP_BUTTONPAD)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

Touching the touchpad produces no events.

By contrast if I select the Logitech mouse 7, I see events for mouse movement, BTN_LEFT and BTN_RIGHT.

I had a look at the BIOS but didn't see anything about enabling/disabling the touchpad.

Any ideas how to kick the touchpad into action or what could be blocking events from the touchpad ?